# Discord.py Server Roles Command, Roles Starting From Down

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I do a server roles command and it working perfectly but the top role is showing in the down. My code is this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def roles(ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        roles = [role for role in guild.roles if role != ctx.guild.default_role]
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Server Roles", description=f"\n \n".join([role.mention for role in roles]))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I want the top role to start form the top not down, how can I do that?

I will be very happy if someone help me :)

Answer (score 0):

`list` type has a reverse method. So if you write `roles.reverse()`, top role will be the first one.

Comment: can you give me code example please, I couldn't understand @Weylyn

Comment: ignore me it worked thank you very much :)